# No ActionBar on Views

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Not sure what happened, I can no longer get apps with an actionbar in Android Studio.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

and

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

for example. It will not show the actionbar.

Comment: Try to replace `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`, usually it works. And call `getActionBar().show();` to show the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your whole XML, then a node `theme` is missing. For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a solution for API Level 11 or higher. Here you just have to use one of the `Holo` Themes to add the ActoinBar.
If you use API Level 10 or lower, try to have a look at the [official Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding).

Comment: it still doesn't seem to want to add it. I'm still getting just a blank screen with no actionbar.

Comment: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` is in my manifest and 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>` 
and 
`<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/fb_dark_blue</item>
    </style>` are in my styles.xml

nothing...

Comment: I've never had to do that in the past, how come I suddenly have to (and I haven't tried it yet, currently at work)

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem with you.
I think you should let your activity extends ActionBarActivity  (not Activity) in Android studio.